# Write spark dataframe to postgres in docker Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: postgresql, docker, pyspark, jdbc, dockerfile

I got this error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.jdbc. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

```
Here is my docker-compose file
postgresdb:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./data
        target: /opt/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql  # create table customer
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
```

```
And this is how I config in pyspark
jdbc_url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"
connection_properties = {
    "user": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}
```

```
result.write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table="customers", mode="overwrite", properties=connection_properties)
```

I want to how to fix this problem. Do I need to install jar file for postgres13 in dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you haven't downloaded the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver JAR yet, download it from Maven Central.
Now place the JAR inside the Spark's jars directory using following command;

```
cp postgresql-<version>.jar /path/to/spark/jars/
```

Now try the code under to configure Spark so that it will start using the driver JAR which you just downloaded.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("YourAppName") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/path/to/spark/jars/postgresql-<version>.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Now you can write to PostgreSQL using your current code. Try the command under, but change the  with the actual version of the JDBC driver you downloaded later.

Comment: This really help. Thank you. It takes me a bit to figure out how to find path of postgres on docker.